# Url Routing in Anchor Tag in asp.net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, html, url-rewriting, anchor, asp.net-4.0

I am using listview and in listview in Item Template, i have anchor tag with href.

```
<a class="linkbutton" href='<%# string.Format("Movie/Hindi-Movie/{0}/{1}",Eval("MovieId"),Eval("MovieName")) %>'><%#Eval("MovieName")%></a>
```

and in Global file

i have

```
routes.MapPageRoute("HindiAboutMovie", "Movie/Hindi-Movie/{MovieId}/{MovieName}", "~/Bollywood/AboutMovie.aspx");
```

This works fine.
but in MovieName i have space between words which makes the url ugly by placing '%' in blank space.

like

```
http://localhost:5703/Movie/Hindi-Movie/43/Kucch%20Luv%20Jaisaa
```

where i am trying to make

```
http://localhost:5703/Movie/Hindi-Movie/43/Kucch-Luv-Jaisaa
```

How to handle this html side in string.Format?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this approach.

In Html i wrote

```
<a class="linkbutton" href='<%# string.Format("Movie/Bollywood-Movie/{0}/{1}",Eval("MovieId"),GetMovieName(Eval("MovieName"))) %>'>
```

and in code behind i wrote a method.

```
public string GetMovieName(object obj)
    {
        string moviename = Convert.ToString(obj);
        string newmoviename= moviename.Replace(" ", "-");
        return newmoviename;
    }
```

This did solve my issue at the moment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a simple adjustment like:

```
<a class="linkbutton" href='<%# String.Format("Movie/Hindi-Movie/{0}/{1}",
Eval("MovieId"), Eval("MovieName").Replace(' ', '-'))
%>'><%# Eval("MovieName") %></a>
```

Comment: That shows an error as object doesn't contain Replace method.